# Ruby gems home on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems

I installed ruby for windows and then rubygems but am getting the following error when trying to use rubygems to install bundler.

```
C:\Users\tgandrews\Ruby\rubygems-1.8.24>gem install bundler --verbose --debug
Exception `NameError' at C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/command_manager.rb:177 - uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:54 - No such file or directory - Z:/
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOENT)
    No such file or directory - Z:/
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:54:in `stat'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:54:in `initialize'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:43:in `new'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:43:in `fetcher'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:110:in `find_gems_with_sources'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:228:in `find_spec_by_name_and_version'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:259:in `install'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:121:in `block in execute'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:115:in `each'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:115:in `execute'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/command.rb:278:in `invoke'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/command_manager.rb:147:in `process_args'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/command_manager.rb:117:in `run'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:65:in `run'
        C:/Ruby193/bin/gem:30:in `<main>'
```

My gem env returns the following

```
C:\Users\tgandrews\Ruby\rubygems-1.8.24>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby193/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be caused by a network drive and incorrect configuration of environment variables like `HOME`, `HOMEDRIVE` and/or `HOMEPATH`

Please see the following section of RubyInstaller troubleshooting section:

https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#wiki-network_drive_home